# Access append using parameters inserts 0 rows

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-insert, ms-access-2016

I am totally new to both Access and SQL and have built a very simple 3 table library-like database to teach myself. I have successfully created `SELECT` queries using parameters but am having problems trying to do the same with `INSERT`. Maybe that just isn't supported? But I am thinking that I don't want to constantly open the table in Datasheet view and add a new record, especially as the table grows.

My syntax is:

```
INSERT INTO books ( BookID, Title, Author )  
SELECT books.BookID, books.Title, books.Author  
FROM books  
WHERE (((books.BookID)=["Enter ISBN"]) AND ((books.Title)=["Enter Title"]) AND ((books.Author)=["Enter Author"]));
```

Running the query prompts me to provide the values but I receive the message "You are about to append O rows" and nothing is added if I click Yes. The `SELECT` part works by itself and will return results already in the table but the `INSERT` won't add a new record to the table. The data types are all short text.

I can successfully add new rows just using the standard `INSERT` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO books ( BookID, Title, Author )  
VALUES ("978-1-250-09966-2", "After Anna", "Lisa Scottoline")
```

But I can't make it work with parameters. This may not even be the best or most efficient way to do this, but again, just trying to teach myself from the ground up and learn efficiencies with practice.

Comment: Are you saying this does not work? -> `INSERT INTO books (BookID, Title, Author) VALUES ([Enter ISBN], [Enter Title], [Enter Author])`

Comment: If not, what happens?  Is there an error message?

Comment: Yes, that works. Thank you. I see the issues with the original syntax now. I didn't know how to properly make the values a supplied parameter at runtime. I have done it successfully in `WHERE` clauses in a `SELECT` statement but not for an `INSERT` statement. I tried to do it through a combination of views (SQL view, and then Design when I couldn't figure it out). The Design view automatically added a `SELECT` statement, even when I picked an append query.